# PHP: Set two arrays into key and value

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible that I can get the data from the other array based on the value from another?

If I input value from array it will return a value from other array.

**Example**:

```
$arr1 = ['A','B','C'];
$arr2 = [1,2,3,];
```

Input: 2
Result: B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do they need to be separate?

You could use `array_combine()` to assign a key to the value and then input is just `$array[$input]` - e.g.

```
$arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
$arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

$arr = array_combine($arr2, $arr1);

echo $arr[$_POST['input']]; # will display 2
```

Comment: Ohh, neat. Didn't think of `array_combine()`.

Comment: @Qirel and I didn't think of `array_search()` xD haha :p

Comment: They have an interesting oposite though: `array_search()` will return the first instance of the result (in this case, 2), while `array_combine()` will return the last. So the two approaches will give different results if there are duplicate values in `$arr2`, as seen here: https://3v4l.org/BZg0e

Comment: We just did ;-) But yeah, sure - if you want to edit in a note in your answer, knock yourself out (don't *actually* knock yourself out, that hurts - or so I've been told).

Comment: @Qirel xD nah, I mean, I guess it's more of a friendly just in-case then a requirement (as $arr1 = unique values).. so I guess comment will do :) and that's true, though, if knocked out quick enough, you skip the pain phase xD

Answer (score 3):

Since your arrays have not been given any specific keys, they are assigned numerically indexes from PHP, starting from zero.

You can then use `array_search()` to get the key of the `$arr2` array, and use that to find the value in `$arr1`.

```php
$key = array_search($input, $arr2);
$output = $arr1[$key];
```

If either array has defined indexes, you can use `array_values()` to just get the values and get the numeric indexes from PHP again.

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/mf688

Answer (score -1):

This function combine 2 or more arrays

```php
<?php
$array1 = array('A', 'B', 'C');
$array2 = array('1', '2', '3');

$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: SHow us how can one use it. How will you get "B" for argument 2?

Answer (score -1):

Working with array $result above (1 of 2 possibility)

```php
<?php echo $result[1]; ?>
```

Or use

```php
<?php
$q = '2'; $key = array_search($q, $result);

if(!$key)
    echo "This search returned no key and value pair";
else
    echo "This search for value: " . $q . " is present in key: " . $key;
?>
```